# Usefulness of consensus number

Tags: consensus, shared-memory

What information and usefulness does knowing the *consensus number* of a shared object give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably cannot do much better than quote the abstract of [Herlihy's original paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/114005.102808?dl=portal&dl=ACM&WantType=periodical&part=periodical&CFTOKEN=49560823&title=ACM+Transactions+on+Programming+Languages+and+Systems+%28TOPLAS%29&idx=114005&CFID=56500239):

> A wait-free implementation of a concurrent data object is one that guarantees that any process can complete any operation in a finite number of steps, regardless of the execution speeds of the other processes. The problem of constructing a wait-free implementation of one data object from another lies at the heart of much recent work in concurrent algorithms, concurrent data structures, and multiprocessor architectures. First, we introduce a simple and general technique, based on reduction to a consensus protocol, for proving statements of the form, “there is no wait-free implementation of X by Y.” We derive a hierarchy of objects such that no object at one level has a wait-free implementation in terms of objects at lower levels. In particular, we show that atomic read/write registers, which have been the focus of much recent attention, are at the bottom of the hierarchy: they cannot be used to construct wait-free implementations of many simple and familiar data types. Moreover, classical synchronization primitives such as test&set and fetch&add, while more powerful than read and write, are also computationally weak, as are the standard message-passing primitives. Second, nevertheless, we show that there do exist simple universal objects from which one can construct a wait-free implementation of any sequential object.